# Vim: replacing start and end of a visual char, line or block

Tags: vim, replace

I am trying to find a shortcut to place a custom comment sequence on my code, e.g.:

```
/*
start of comment
blah
end of comment
/**/
```

(it is easier to void the comment by just adding a / to the beginning)

I would like to do this in Vim by selecting a visual line, block or char and adding '/*' characters at the beginning of the block and '/**/' at the end, plus newlines.

After selecting some lines (Shift-V) I tried this:

```
'<,'>s/\(.*\)/\/*\r\1\r\/**\//
```

But it adds the comment chars at EACH newline.

How can I only apply the substitution at the beginning and end of the selected range?

Thanks 
gm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the following substitution command.

```
:'<s~^~/*\r~|'>s~$~\r/**/~
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked.
I did not know about the tilde, I will read more about it.

Comment: @gattu:  The main idea is to use two consecutive substitution commands.  Regarding `~` here, one can use almost any single-byte character for surrounding patterns instead of default `/` (see `:help E146`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

    `:'<,'>s-\(\_.*\)-/*\r\1\r/**/-`

**Update:** I believe this is not the best way of achieving the result you want. I recommend you to read some information about `'< and '>` marks. With this mark the commenting can be implemented more efficiently. Also, there is lot of ready solutions for this task.